# override getLoadedProductCollection of \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct

Tags: magento2, blocks, collection, overrides, product-list

I am overriding getLoadedProductCollection() in my block where performing some custom query

```
     public function getLoadedProductCollection()
        {
            $myCategory = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('category_details');

            if ($myCategory['category_id'] === '96') {

     $collection = $this->collectionFactory; // dont forget to inject the product factory in your constructor
                        $collection = $collection->create()->getCollection();
                        $collection = $collection->addFieldToFilter(
                            'entity_id',
                            ['in' => $array]
                        );
                        $collection = $collection->addAttributeToSelect($this->catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
                            ->addMinimalPrice()
                            ->addFinalPrice()
                            ->addTaxPercents()
                            ->addUrlRewrite($myCategory);
                        return $collection;
           }
else {
             return parent::getLoadedProductCollection();
    }
```

But the problem is when my category id is 96 its run the upper query and show but in with in second it fired

> return parent::getLoadedProductCollection();

and then return null